# Debug android Device

Tags: adb, usb

I have a problem with many of my android devices,I figured out that my devices micro usb is easy to damage ( sad reality) so when I try to debug returns for me an empty List of devices attached,

My question is so how i can debug my devices now with a damaged micro usb ?

Knowing that my devices have an ethernet port + usb standard port.

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Rooted or not? You should be able to use ADB Wireless easily if rooted.

Comment: Devices are not rooted .

Comment: Are you sure the USB port is damaged? It could be just a bad USB cable, or corrupted drivers on your PC, which can happen if you switch between multiple devices from different manufacturers often.  Can you try reinstalling the drivers and trying a different cable?  Also, is the device rooted?

Comment: I am sure that is not related to driver or cable, and the device is not rooted.

Answer (score 0):

ADB is able to work over Wi-Fi, but it needs to be enabled on the Android device first.  Usually this is done by using command `adb tcpip 5555` while the phone is plugged in via USB.  However if the USB port is damaged, you will need to be rooted to enable the wireless adb mode.

If your phone is rooted, connect it to the same Wi-Fi network as your PC,  install a [Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) app, open it and run the following commands:

```
su
```

Accept the prompt to allow access,

```
setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555
stop adbd
start adbd
```

If the above succeeded, you should then be able to connect from your PC by using command `adb connect <IP of your phone here>`, for example `adb connect 192.168.1.100`.  If successful, you should be able to continue debugging.

Comment: Are you sure it needs either USB or root to enable that? There are several [ADB Wireless](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_adb#group_840) widgets not requiring root.

Comment: @Izzy I looked through every app on that list.  Every one either requires root, or requires connecting the device via USB and running adb tcpip command.

Comment: I am aware about the rooted device solution, I am wondering if I can debug my device over an ethernet micro usb adaptor ?